# scrapy NBA schedule not collating correctly

Tags: python, scrapy

Trying to get a simple web scrape up and running. The goal is to dump the dt gm tm and ntv classes into csv - eventually. Here it is json for clarity. One step at a time.

here's the spider:

```
import scrapy

class QuotesSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "schedule"
    start_urls = [
        'http://www.nba.com/schedules/national_tv_schedule/',
    ]

    def parse(self, response):
        for game in response.css('td'):
            yield {
                'date': game.css('td.dt::text').extract(),
                'time': game.css('td.tm::text').extract(),
            }
```

really simple - but spits out like so: (truncated for brevity)

```
[
{"date": ["Sat, Oct 1", " ", "Sun, Oct 2", "Mon, Oct 3", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " "], "time": ["7:30 pm", "8:00 pm", "8:00 pm", "2:30 pm", "8:00 pm", "8:00 pm", "8:30 pm", "9:00 pm", "10:00 pm", "10:00 pm", "7:00 pm", "7:00 pm", "8:00 pm", "8:00 pm", "10:00 pm", "10:30 pm", "2:30 pm", "7:00 pm", "10:00 pm", "10:30 pm", "7:00 pm", "7:00 pm", "7:30 pm", "7:30 pm", "8:00 pm", "10:30 pm", "10:00 pm"]},
{"date": [], "time": []},
{"date": [], "time": []},
{"date": [], "time": []},
{"date": [], "time": []},
{"date": [], "time": []},
{"date": ["Sat, Oct 1"], "time": []},
{"date": [], "time": []},
{"date": [], "time": ["7:30 pm"]},
{"date": [], "time": []},
{"date": [" "], "time": []},
{"date": [], "time": []},
{"date": [], "time": ["8:00 pm"]},
{"date": [], "time": []},
{"date": ["Sun, Oct 2"], "time": []},
{"date": [], "time": []},
{"date": [], "time": ["8:00 pm"]},
{"date": [], "time": []},
{"date": ["Mon, Oct 3"], "time": []},
{"date": [], "time": []},
{"date": [], "time": ["2:30 pm"]},
{"date": [], "time": []},
{"date": [" "], "time": []},
{"date": [], "time": []},
{"date": [], "time": ["8:00 pm"]},
{"date": [], "time": []},
{"date": [" "], "time": []},
{"date": [], "time": []},
{"date": [], "time": ["8:00 pm"]},
{"date": [], "time": []},
{"date": [" "], "time": []},
{"date": [], "time": []},
{"date": [], "time": ["8:30 pm"]},
{"date": [], "time": []},
{"date": [" "], "time": []},
{"date": [], "time": []},
{"date": [], "time": ["9:00 pm"]},
{"date": [], "time": []},
{"date": [" "], "time": []},
{"date": [], "time": []},
{"date": [], "time": ["10:00 pm"]},
{"date": [], "time": []},
{"date": [" "], "time": []},
{"date": [], "time": []},
{"date": [], "time": ["10:00 pm"]},
{"date": [], "time": []}
]
```

The first dict has the right data in the right order, but not collated. The following dicts have not matched up the data in the first dict correctly. I tried a while statement to take out newlines but was unsuccessful.

Any suggestions? I built this using the Scrapy tutorial. I know that I will eventually need to insert the correct dates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably want to be more specific on the table and rows you select.

Take a look at the HTML for the start of the schedule:

```
   <div id="scheduleMain" style="margin:0 5px 0 0!important;">
   <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="genSchedTable tvindex">
      <tr class="header">
         <td colspan="4">NATIONAL TV SCHEDULE - 2016-17</td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="title">
         <td class="date">Date</td>
         <td class="game">Teams</td>
         <td class="time">Time (ET)</td>
         <td class="natTV">Network</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td class="dt">Mon, Oct 3</td>
         <td class="gm"><a href="/thunder">Oklahoma City</a> @ <a href="/real_madrid">Real Madrid</a><br>Preseason

         </td>
         <td class="tm">2:30 pm</td>
         <td class="ntv"><img border="0" src="http://i.cdn.turner.com/nba/nba/images/shrinkee_NBATV.gif"><img border="0" src="http://i.cdn.turner.com/nba/nba/images/shrinkee_NBAC.gif"></td>
      </tr>
      ...
```

You can see that the table you're after is inside a `<div id="scheduleMain">`.

And you should select table rows ( `<tr>`), not table cells in your for loop, and in each loop iteration, select the cells for time and date:

```
def parse(self, response):
    for game in response.css('#scheduleMain > table tr:nth-child(n+3)'):
        yield {
            'date': game.css('td.dt::text').extract(),
            'time': game.css('td.tm::text').extract(),
        }
```

`tr:nth-child(n+3)` is used to select rows 3, 4, 5... (the 1st 2 rows are headers)

Comment: the end of the response.css string needs a close quotes. It works much better, thank you so much for your help!

Comment: Right! sorry about the typo